# How do I make abiword show it's icon in unity launcher?

Tags: 11.04, launcher, icons

I prefer Abiword instead of Libreoffice, so i right-clicked on an opendocument-file, selected "open with" and in the window I chose to make it open with the command "abiword", and when I double-click the document it opens in abiword, but in the launcher it shows a gray question mark instead of the abiword icon. It's a minor thing I know, but it bugs me. How can you start it and have the *real* icon show?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to, instead of opening a document, open Abiword through Menu > Applications?

Comment: Yes, then it works fine, but I want to double-click-open too.

Comment: I'm at mobile right now and I can't find a solution. In the mean while you can add this bug here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/WindowMatching

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. open AbiWord from your applications menu (Super + A)
2. once AbiWord is open look to see if its icon is present in the Launcher. If not, I don't know. But if so you can right-click this Launcher icon and select the Pin to launcher option
3. now try opening a document and see if it uses the "?" icon or the AbiWord icon.

Comment: It works fine if I do it that way, but I want to be able to open it from the file manager and still have consistent icons, is that possible?

Comment: Once you pin the "non-?" icon to the Launcher try opening from the File Manager with the expectation that it will now use the "non-?" icon. That is, does it still use the ? icon even after pinning the graphical icon to the LauncheR?

Comment: No, it does not, it creates a ?-icon, even if the real deal is pinned

Comment: @Martin Josefsson: when you open a folder in nautilus and look at an AbiWord file, it has an icon or it has "?" ?

Comment: Nope, then it works as expected with the Abiword icon.